# Oracle - Inconsistent data types : expected CHAR got REF

Tags: oracle, ref

Could you all pls help me with the following ?

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

I get the above error when executing the select statement of the script I have attached. In the screenshot, I have highlighted the select statement giving me the error.

```
CREATE TYPE exchanges_traded AS VARRAY(3) OF VARCHAR2(25)
/
CREATE TYPE stock_t AS OBJECT(
  company VARCHAR(15),
  currentPrice NUMBER(8,2),
  exchanges  exchanges_traded,
  lastDividend NUMBER(4,2),
  eps NUMBER(4,2)
)
/
CREATE TYPE address_t AS OBJECT(
  streeetNo NUMBER(3),
  streetName VARCHAR(8),
  suburb VARCHAR(10),
  state VARCHAR(12),
  pin NUMBER(5)
)
/

CREATE TYPE investment_t AS OBJECT(
  company REF stock_t ,
  purchasePrice NUMBER(8,2),
  invdate DATE,
  quantity NUMBER(10)
)
/
CREATE TYPE investment_list AS TABLE OF investment_t
/

CREATE TYPE clients_t AS OBJECT(
  name VARCHAR(25),
  address address_t,
  investments investment_list
)
/


CREATE TABLE stocks OF stock_t(
  CONSTRAINT companyName_pk PRIMARY KEY(company)
)
/

CREATE TABLE clients OF clients_t(
 CONSTRAINT clientName_pk PRIMARY KEY(name)
)NESTED TABLE investments STORE AS investment_tab
/


select e.COLUMN_VALUE exchange from stocks s, TABLE(s.exchanges) e
/

ALTER TABLE investment_tab ADD SCOPE FOR (company) IS stocks
/


INSERT INTO stocks VALUES(stock_t('BHP',10.50, exchanges_traded('Sydney','NewYork'), 1.50, 3.20))
/
INSERT INTO stocks VALUES(stock_t('IBM',70.00,exchanges_traded('NewYork','London','Tokyo'),4.25,10.00))
/
INSERT INTO stocks VALUES(stock_t('INTEL',76.50,exchanges_traded('NewYork','London'),5.00,12.40))
/
INSERT INTO stocks VALUES(stock_t('FORD',40.00,exchanges_traded('NewYork'),2.00,8.50))
/
INSERT INTO stocks VALUES(stock_t('GM',60.00,exchanges_traded('NewYork'),2.50,9.20))
/
INSERT INTO stocks VALUES(stock_t('INFOSYS',45.00,exchanges_traded('NewYork'),3.00,7.80))
/



INSERT INTO clients VALUES(clients_t('John Smith',address_t(3,' East Av','Bentley','WA', 6102),investment_list(investment_t((SELECT REF(s) FROM stocks s WHERE s.company = 'BHP'),12.00,'02-OCT-01',1000),
                                                                                               investment_t((SELECT REF(s) FROM stocks s WHERE s.company = 'BHP'),10.50 ,'08-JUN-02',2000),
                                                                                               investment_t((SELECT REF(s) FROM stocks s WHERE s.company = 'IBM'),58.00,'12-FEB-00',500),
                                                                                               investment_t((SELECT REF(s) FROM stocks s WHERE s.company = 'IBM'),65.00,'10-APR-01',1200),
                                                                                               investment_t((SELECT REF(s) FROM stocks s WHERE s.company = 'INFOSYS'),64.00,'11-AUG-01',1000))))
/

INSERT INTO clients VALUES(clients_t('Jill Brody',address_t(42,'Bent St','Perth','WA', 6001),investment_list(investment_t((SELECT REF(s) FROM stocks s WHERE s.company = 'INTEL'),35.00,'30-JAN-00 ',300),
                                                                                               investment_t((SELECT REF(s) FROM stocks s WHERE s.company = 'INTEL'),54.00,'30-JAN-01',400),
                                                                                               investment_t((SELECT REF(s) FROM stocks s WHERE s.company = 'INTEL'),60.00,'02-OCT-01',200),
                                                                                               investment_t((SELECT REF(s) FROM stocks s WHERE s.company = 'FORD'),40.00,'05-OCT-99 ',300),
                                                                                               investment_t((SELECT REF(s) FROM stocks s WHERE s.company = 'GM'),55.50,'12-DEC-00',500))))
/



select c.name , c.address , i.company,i.purchasePrice,i.invdate,i.quantity
from clients c , table(c.investments)i
/

select c.name , i.purchasePrice 
from clients c , table(c.investments)i
/
```

I have been struggling a lot with this. pls help

Thank You

Comment: I just copied to fiddle and it all works fine. Could you check https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=5ba06cb200ca8f09f2e8fe8eea64b2c4

Comment: @Prasadika What is the actual error you are getting. If so, including it in your original post. Not in the comments section.